# How to export an excel with mysql table data with fields having images

Tags: php, mysql, excel

[image] My requirement is to download the data filled by students and stored in server.
The fields contain images that need to be filled as a column in Excel.

[image]

Comment: Pls click on ' enter image description here ' to view the image code